# Should I stay on a terrible job for one more month?

Tags: software-industry, management, conflict, working-conditions, japan

In June 2018 I had an offer for a job in Japan. The conditions were fine: 9:00-18:00, paid vacation, language support and an ok salary. Personally I moved there because I really enjoy culture and aesthetics of this country, so as travelling, and I decided to take a shot.

The Japan is great. It is a great experience. But job is a huge fail. Apart from technical aspects and the style of development here, there are some problems that are directly connected with the fact that my employer lied about working conditions. So, one by one:

1. The job is not 9:00 - 18:00. You have to work at least 150 hours in a month, which leads to some terrible months where you have to stay at work up to 22:00. This is basically because I am working as an outsource (about that I was not informed too) and there is not a single word about 9:00 - 18:00 working hours in contract between my primary company and secondary. Just a minimum of 150 and maximum of 190 hours/month.
2. There is no paid vacation. As you can see from point 1, I have to work for certain amount of time. So if I take a day off, I have to distribute working hours of that day to other, leading to even longer workdays.

I am going to leave the company in the nearest two months. And as I heard from former employees, this is going to be messy.

So, my questions are:

1. Do you think I should leave ASAP? There is no professional growth in this workplace and I can't even have a good interviews because I am working at least until 19:00. From the visa point of view I am fine, and from the Japanese law point of view I have to work for 15 days before leaving, that is the only restriction.
2. Should I conflict with the person who lied me about my job? There is also a thing called financial year, and it ends in April in Japan, so I think it is better for my employer if I stay until that moment. But should I care about that stuff?
3. I am thinking of starting leaving at 18:00. This is stated in the only contract that I have signed. But my local bosses are going to be unhappy. It is really not their fault that my primary company is so full of sh*t. Some advice?

P.S. I tried talking to a person who hired me, but he sees no problem there and just trying to be a good guy, blah blah blah, while in fact only thing he does is demagogy.

Comment: What do you mean by 9-18? like in 24 hours? and what do you mean work until atleast the 19? and whats leaving at the 18 mean? what is this confusing hour date system you are using.

Comment: @Shadowzee I assume 9-18 means 9 a.m. to 6 p.m. (24 hour clock is common outside U.S.).

Comment: @mhwombat Oh I get it... OP mean he wanted to start leaving at 6pm instead of leaving at 7pm... I thought he meant months because the title was "should i stay on ... for one more month"

Comment: @mhwombat basically I am thinking of leaving in April (end of financial year) or in March, that's where title comes from. Just decided to put all the questions together.

Comment: 150 / 4.3 = 34 hours a week = 6.8 hours a day.  How is that bad?

Comment: @solarflare 150 is a minimum. Usually in Japan you have around 19-20 workdays. For 19-20 workdays 168 hours is standard in current company. 168/20 gives you around 8.4, which sounds not so terrible. But on some months, when there are many holidays (January, May, August) it comes down to 15 working days. Resulting in 10 hours workday. Apart from that, if you want to take a "paid" day-off, you have less days to fulfill this 150-190 barrier.

Comment: @mjazz, Could you please clarify something in your post? You mention a contract between the primary and secondary company that does not list some of the benefits/conditions of your employment. But, what is in the contracts that you personally signed with either company? Are any of the benefits mentioned there?

Comment: I think I can guess the company, BTW!   What does this mean:  "And as I heard from former employees, this is going to be messy."   Why would leaving be messy?    You just send an email "My last day will be X"   What is messy?  Pls explain!  Thanks!

Comment: @SambalMinion sure! I have signed only one contract - with my primary company. In that contract, all the benefits are mentioned. However, in a contract between my primary and secondary company, there are no benefits mentioned.

Comment: @mjazz You just follow the contract that you have signed. If another company messed up, signing different things with one entity and different things with another, that's not your problem. Just make them well aware that this is what you've signed and this is what you'll do. BTW, see also https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30640/are-workers-in-japan-expected-to-work-overtime-daily (though I assume you'll know it already)

Comment: @Fattie your boss calls you and starts yelling at you.There is stuff like "We brought you here, you are such an ungrateful person!" etc. Not much worried about that, actually :)

Comment: I understand the culture in Japan is totally different, however isn't it law that you should be automatically entitled to 10 days leave after 6 months service, which then increases annually based on years service to the company?Source:  https://talenthub.jp/blog/working-in-japan/holidays-and-paid-annual-leave/

Comment: Japan is famous for its brutal salaryman hours and work culture. Not all answers here seem to be aware of this important cultural issue.

Comment: You ask about working another month in the title, but the only thing I see in the body of the question is that it would be good for your employer.  If you're not happy with your employer, and feel like you've been deceived, why would you care about that?

Comment: Also, you say that you're required to work a certain number of hours a month.  What does your actual contract, the one you signed, say about that?  If it says you work 9-18 with paid vacation, how does your employer require you to work outside that?  I can understand why they'd want you to, but not why they can require it.

Comment: @DavidThornley because my secondary company signed a contract with my primary contract, which is different from the contract that I have signed. And as I am outsourcing for a secondary company, they use the contract that they have signed with my primary company. I am thinking of drawing a diagram because it is not so easy to understand I guess :)

Comment: @mjazz Your contract is your concern.  You need to do what you signed on to do, and you aren't legally obligated to do any more.  Your employer's contracts aren't.  You're not bound by them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once you fulfill your legal obligations leave.

> It is really not their fault that my primary company

It's not your fault that it's not their fault. Don't allow it to be a factor in your career, you don't owe them anything.

> Should I conflict with the person who lied me about my job?

Not unless you must, just get out as quietly and professionally as you can. There is no plus side to getting into the blame game.

Answer (score 3):

> I am thinking of starting leaving at 18

Sounds good.
You don't like it there, and you'd have time to look for other opportunities

---

On another note...

> The job is not 9 - 18. You have to work at least 150 hours in a month

How many days do you work?
I'm supposed to work 40/week which is 160 hours in February and more in the rest of the months.

I don't understand the math, 9-18 is 9hrs. Subtract an unpaid hour for lunch gives an eight hour day.
You would be over 150 hours on your 19th working day.

Comment: The thing is, 150 is a minimum. For February I have around 165 hours to fulfill.

Comment: @mjazz The minimum varies by month?  Regardless, you either leave at 6 PM and risk making them mad, or work an extra 30 minutes every day - neither choice seems horrible to me. Or since you aren't too concerned with what they think, why can't you just take a day off without pay?

Answer (score 1):

> "Should I stay on a terrible job for one more month?"

The simple answer here seems to be "No, leave now if you want to".

I can not see any reason, whatsoever, explained in the question, why you would not simply leave.

Comment: Pending the 15 day legal requirement of course.